# Filter and display mongodb documents

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to MongoDB so I apologize if my terminology is incorrect. I'm working on an        e-commerce project (learning project) with express, mongoose and ejs, and I want to add a filter option into the 'All products' page. So for example if someone wants to view 'Sports' products only, I'd like to be able to update (PUT) the current page with 'Sports' products only.

To achieve this right now with my current skill set, I would create a separate route for each product category, `/products/sports` and then  `Product.find({ category: 'Sports' })` in my controller, and then display it in my ejs file with something like
`<% sportsProducts.forEach(product => { %> <% display each product here %>`

I feel like this is not the right approach at all, as it would be difficult to scale the project, and I could run into issues with displaying a certain amount of products per page. Is this something I need an API or AJAX for? I would much rather stay away from those if possible.

I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction, since a lot of mongodb's capabilities are unknown to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can follow these two approaches

1. make your route as dynamic like /products/:category then in code

   Product.find({category:req.params.category})
2. Add a category as query param in your route /products?category=sports

   Product.find({category:req.query.category})

Comment: thank you! that first approach works perfectly. i have a follow up question if you are willing to help me again; say I have 20 'Sports' products, and only want to display 5 products per page, how can I approach that?

Comment: simply sort the data first then add skip and limit after find expression
like Product.find({conditions}).sort(in order you want).skip(x).limit(5)
you can fetch this skip from query params based on page*5

To study more on this simply study how pagination works!